# how to run for loop using timeinterval ionic 3

Tags: javascript, typescript, for-loop, ionic3

```
starttimer() {


    for(let i=0;i<=5;i++)
    {

      console.log(i);
      var loopTimeout = setTimeout( () => {


        console.log("timer");

   }, 3000);
  }
```

actual output:

0

1

2

3

timer

> Expected output:
>
> 0
>
> after 3 sec
>
> 1
>
> after 3 sec
>
> 2
>
> after 3 sec
>
> 3

based on timing it will execute every line of the loop

does anyone have an idea about that?

Comment: You need to move `console.log(i);` to inside the setTimeout callback.

Comment: @Gavin - Even that will give _3_ in all occurrences :) Not _0, 1, 2, 3.._

Comment: setTimeout how i can call back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use async await to do it:

```
async function starttimer() {


    for(let i=0;i<=5;i++)
    {
      console.log(i);
      await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 3000));    
    }
}

starttimer();
```

Comment: async functions can await the resolving of promises, so that bit that says `await new Promise` is almost like a Sleep function in other languages.

Comment: Please mark answer as correct if it answered your question.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Promise, because you call 3 timeouts in the same time

```
function wait3sec() {
    return new Promise(resolve => { setTimeout(() => resolve("tick"), 3000);});
}

async function startTimer() {
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        await wait3sec();
        console.log(i);
    }

}
```

inspiration: [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

Answer (score 1):

I would advise going for the answers with the async/await examples. It will produce less complex and more readable code.

But just to show you how it can work without async/await:

```
function startTimer() {
  let i = 0;

  tick();

  function tick() {
    console.log(i);

    if (i < 3) {
      i ++;
      setTimeout(tick, 3000);
    }
  }
};

startTimer();
```

The trick is defining `i` outside of the `tick` function and increment it inside the `tick` function.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem once.

I think this should fix it.

```
starttimer() {


    for(let i=0;i<=5;i++)
    {

      console.log(i);
      var loopTimeout = setTimeout( function(){


        console.log("timer");

   }, 3000);
  }
```